# KnownType Serialization Issue

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontract

Having read the documentation and many many articles I believe the following should work but it doesn't.

This is how my datacontracts are structured.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Friend))]
public class Person
{
   private string name;

   [DataMember]
   public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; }}

   private Place location;

   [DataMember]
   public Place Location { get { return location; } set { location = value; }}
}

[DataContract]
public class Friend : Person
{
   private int mobile;

   [DataMember]
   public int Mobile { get { return mobile; } set { mobile = value; }}
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(City))]
public class Place
{
   private int altitude;

   [DataMember]
   public int Altitude { get { return altitude; } set { altitude = value; }}
}

[DataContract]
public class City : Place
{
   private int zipCode;

   [DataMember]
   public int ZipCode { get { return zipCode; } set { zipCode = value; }}
}
```

The client sends the following example object:

```
Person tom = new Friend();
tom.Name = "Tom";

Place office = new City();
office.Altitude = 500;
office.ZipCode = 900500;

tom.Location = office;
```

The issue is for some reason none of the Place values are serialized.

What mistake am I making?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the altitude getting serialized? Or nothing regarding the place at all?

Comment: No property of Place is getting serialized when client submits Person.

Comment: Couple problems: 1) Your client code does not compile: office.ZipCode is not a valid assignment. 2) I pasted your data contracts into VS2010, made a function that returns a "Person", and called it using the WCF Test container. It worked. So the problem is probably with code that isn't shown in the question.

Comment: 1) This was just an example to illustrate the issue I was having. Actual code compiles :)

Comment: Also, I have tested DataContracts using DataContractSerializer and the problematic objects get serialized and deserialized  successfully. However, when the same object is sent by WCF Client the values of Place object are not serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration turns out my datacontract design was flawed :(

Comment: Care to share the flaw? Several people put time into trying to understand your issue. It would be nice if you would share the root cause now that you found it.

Comment: In the actual implementation both Person and Friend had reference to Location. Client was setting properties on Location object in Person but not on Location object on Friend. This was the reason properties of Location object were not serialized.

Answer (score 0):

DataContract uses opt-in, Serializeable uses Opt-out. That is why it works when using Serializeable. 
You need to mark the backing fields as DataMembers, not the properties:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Friend))]
public class Person
{
   [DataMember]
   private string name;

   public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; }}

   [DataMember]
   private Place location;

   public Place Location { get { return location; } set { location = value; }}
}

[DataContract]
public class Friend : Person
{
   [DataMember]
   private int mobile;

   public int Mobile { get { return mobile; } set { mobile = value; }}
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(City))]
public class Place
{
   [DataMember]
   private int altitude;

   public int Altitude { get { return altitude; } set { altitude = value; }}
}

[DataContract]
public class City : Place
{
   [DataMember]   
   private int zipCode;

   public int ZipCode { get { return zipCode; } set { zipCode = value; }}
}
```

Comment: 1) I have not tried using Serializable, I tested with DataContractSerializer.

Comment: 2) According to documentation DataMember attribute can be applied to properties so I don't think this is the issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=VS.85).aspx